# haproxy tls1.0 to tls1.3 proxy

Tags: ssl, proxy, haproxy

I have a very old application on prem that can only talk tls1.0 and I need to talk to a internet site on tls1.3.  Can I use HAProxy to configure my local listener to listen on https tls 1.0 and forward these GET and POST requests to and internet facing API on TLS1.3?

If not HAProxy, what Can I use?

Thanks
Tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using HAProxy, You may specify different ciphers for **bind** and **servers** in the global section, which could look like this:

```
global
    # modern bind configuration, Only TLS1.3 enabled.
    ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11 no-tlsv12 no-tls-tickets
```

or

```
global   
   # old configuration for the server side, only sslv3 and below are disabled, tls1.0,tls1.2 and tls1.3 are all enabled.
   ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA
    ssl-default-server-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    ssl-default-server-options no-sslv3 no-tls-tickets
    # you may also add the below:
    ssl-server-verify                none
```

I hope this works for you. HAProxy is very much flexible to suit your needs.
*Reference: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=haproxy*

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same problem and on internet was no solution, but after 2 days I finally find solution with HAProxy (maybe it can help someone).

My case:
Traffic -> myfakehost.com (listenning TLS1.0) -> myhost.com (listenning TLS1.2).

`/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`:

```
frontend old_maps
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/mycertificate.pem force-tlsv10
  mode tcp
  default_backend new_maps

backend new_maps
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option forwardfor
  http-request set-header Host myhost.com
  server mymaps myhost.com:443 ssl check verify none
```

As you can see I had few problems with certificates and I need use `set-header` option to change original URL to new URL.

Note: `mycertificate.pem` need to have in my case (private key, server certificate, intermediate certificate, root certificate) and `myfakehost.com` is alias for `localhost` in `/etc/hosts`

Debug tools:

```
 curl -v https://myfakehost.com
 openssl s_client -showcerts -connect myfakehost.com:443
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this this will help someone. If you want it to be set on a specific bind you can do so via the following:

```
bind YOUR_IP:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/ alpn h2,http/1.1 ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!CAMELLIA@SECLEVEL=1 ssl-min-ver TLSv1.0
```

Note the `SECLEVEL=1`.

Hope it helps someone.